# How can I create a label that always stays near a polyline in Cesium.js?

Tags: javascript, typescript, cesiumjs, geodesic-sphere

I have a situation where I'm using Cesium.js entities to draw bearing lines from a point. In addition, I'd like to have a label attached to these bearing lines on the entity to show what it is. This is easy enough to do by attaching a label to the polyline entity. So far what I'm doing is creating a "really long" line along the bearing from the reference point and using the midpoint along that line as an anchor for the label (in Typescript):

```
 let newEntity : Cesium.Entity;
 let gccalc : gc.GreatCircle = new gc.GreatCircle();
 let bearing : number = 45.0; //Bearing for the line

 //this.currentPos is the lat/lon for the reference point for our bearing line
 //gccalc is a simple class for computing great circle lines and has been omitted here (it is not relevant to the problem)
 let destination  =  gccalc.destination(this.currentPos[0], this.currentPos[1], bearing, 1500, 'MI');
 let anchorLabel = gccalc.destination(this.currentPos[0], this.currentPos[1], bearing, 50, 'MI');

 const lineMat  = new Cesium.PolylineDashMaterialProperty({
                    color : this.typeColorMap.get(contact.type)
                  });

 const poses = Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegreesArrayHeights([this.currentPos[1], this.currentPos[0], 500, 
            destination[1], destination[0], 500]); //500 is an arbitrary altitude for aesthetics            

 const nameString : string = "StringLabel";
 let lineLabel = {
            text: nameString,
            font: '16px Helvetica',
            fillColor : this.typeColorMap.get(contact.type),
            outlineColor : Cesium.Color.BLACK,
            outlineWidth : 2,
            verticalOrigin : Cesium.VerticalOrigin.MIDDLE,
            horizontalOrigin : Cesium.HorizontalOrigin.MIDDLE,
            pixelOffset : new Cesium.Cartesian2(20, 0),
            //pixelOffsetScaleByDistance : new Cesium.NearFarScalar(1.5e-1, 30.0, 1.5e7, 0.5)
  };

  let bearingLine = new Cesium.PolylineGraphics();
  bearingLine.positions = poses;
  bearingLine.width = 4;
  bearingLine.material = lineMat;
  bearingLine.arcType = Cesium.ArcType.NONE;


  const lineEntity =  {
        name : 'Bearing Line',
        polyline : bearingLine,
        position : Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(anchorLabel[1], anchorLabel[0]),
        show : true,
        label : new Cesium.LabelGraphics(
            lineLabel,
        ) as Cesium.LabelGraphics,

 };
 newEntity = new Cesium.Entity(lineEntity);
```

But the problem is the label is in geodesic (lat/lon) coordinates and does not stay on the screen as the user zooms in and out on the bearing line. So I also attempted to scale the position using the pixelOffsetScaleByDistance property, but this also doesn't work very well, and doesn't keep the label near the line 
under 3d rotations (because the X and Y scaling would technically have to change).

It seems what I *really* need are the screen-space positions of the line endpoints, and a way to create the entity label at that midpoint. Is there a way to do this? **If not, what is the best way to ensure that my label is always near my polyline regardless of user interactions with the Cesium map (such as zooms and rotations)?**

To give an idea of what I'm trying to do, here's a screencap of Cesium with the labels as implemented. They look correct here, but only because I've made sure the zoom level and rotation is correct:
[image: Screencap of attempt so far]

Comment: Did you figure this out?  If so, please post answer.